# Able to get all invoices from xero but didn't able to get all account facing oauth_problem problem

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, xero-api

```
import os
import requests
import base64
from xero.auth import OAuth2Credentials
from xero import Xero
from xero.constants import XeroScopes
my_scope = [XeroScopes.OFFLINE_ACCESS, XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_CONTACTS, XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_SETTINGS, XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTIONS_READ,
            XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTIONS, XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_CONTACTS_READ, XeroScopes.ACCOUNTING_SETTINGS_READ, ]

CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
REFRESH_TOKEN_PATH = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, "config", "refresh_token2.txt")

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxx'
CALLBACK_URI = 'https://xero.com/'
TENANT_ID = 'xxxxx'

credentials = OAuth2Credentials(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, token=TOKEN,
                                callback_uri=CALLBACK_URI, tenant_id=TENANT_ID, scope=my_scope)
XERO = Xero(credentials)
invoices = XERO.invoices.all()
print invoices
accounts = XERO.accounts.all()
print accounts
```

While getting all accounts from xero or get_attachment_data in xero facing oauth_problem error in return, using new token every time.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Is that Callback URI valid? I thought it was supposed to be something on your server.

Comment: Yes Callback URI is valid, it's working for invoices api but it's not working for accounts api. It's returning key (KeyError: 'oauth_problem'). I am using this one pyxero docs for this:
https://pypi.org/project/pyxero/

Comment: I don't know Python at all, so no point me following your link. Is it a scope issue, do you have the necessary permissions? If some things work and some things don't, that can be a pointer to a scope problem.

Comment: Thank you, I solve this problem with help of xero support.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the solution as an answer, in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, I will post that soon

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero/issues/160 includes several reports of `KeyError: 'oauth_problem'` and seems to suggest that it is indicative of an underlying permissions issue - is that how you resolved it with Xero Support?

Answer (score 0):

The original poster's issue was resolved by ensuring the accounting.settings scope was included on the authorization link and so also included in the access token.

You can check the access token by decoding it eg using code or by pasting into jwt.io to see what scopes are included in the token.